# AutoMapper Ignores Nested Members

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

I have the following domain entity (Customer):

```cs
public abstract class AuditableEntity<TId> : IAuditableEntity<TId>
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public int LeadSource { get; set; }
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string? Number { get; set; }
    public string? Postcode { get; set; }
    public string? Street { get; set; }
    public string? Locality { get; set; }
    public string? Town { get; set; }
    public string? County { get; set; }
    public string? Country { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string? Mobile { get; set; }
    public string? Home { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

With the following DTO's

```cs
public class AddEditCustomerCommand : IRequest<Result<int>>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Locality { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int LeadSource { get; set; }
}

public class GetAllPagedCustomersResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Locality { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int LeadSource { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following mapper:

```cs
public class CustomerProfile : Profile
{
    public CustomerProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<AddEditCustomerCommand, Customer>()
            .ForMember(
                m => m.Address,
                options => options.MapFrom(p => new Address
                {
                    Number = p.Number,
                    Postcode = p.Postcode,
                    Street = p.Street,
                    Locality = p.Locality,
                    Town = p.Town,
                    County = p.County,
                    Country = p.Country
                }))
            .ForMember(
                m => m.Contact,
                options => options.MapFrom(p => new Contact
                {
                    Mobile = p.Mobile,
                    Home = p.Home,
                    Email = p.Email
                }))
            .ForMember(m => m.CreatedBy, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.CreatedOn, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.LastModifiedBy, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.LastModifiedOn, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.Orders, options => options.Ignore())
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<GetAllPagedCustomersResponse, Customer>()
            .ForMember(
                m => m.Address,
                options => options.MapFrom(p => new Address
                {
                    Number = p.Number,
                    Postcode = p.Postcode,
                    Street = p.Street,
                    Locality = p.Locality,
                    Town = p.Town,
                    County = p.County,
                    Country = p.Country
                }))
            .ForMember(
                m => m.Contact,
                options => options.MapFrom(p => new Contact
                {
                    Mobile = p.Mobile,
                    Home = p.Home,
                    Email = p.Email
                }))
            .ForMember(m => m.CreatedBy, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.CreatedOn, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.LastModifiedBy, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.LastModifiedOn, options => options.Ignore())
            .ForMember(m => m.Orders, options => options.Ignore())
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I have enabled config validation `_mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` which shows no errors with the mapping profile.

When I create a new `Customer` using the `AddEditCustomerCommand`, everything works and the DTO is mapped to the entity which properly adds the `Address` and `Contact`.

But for some reason when I get the `Customer` and it is mapped to the `GetAllPagedCustomersResponse`, the nested properties aren't being mapped and are `null`.

```json
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": 0,
    "FirstName": "Scott",
    "LastName": "Kane",
    "Number": null,
    "Postcode": null,
    "Street": null,
    "Locality": null,
    "Town": null,
    "County": null,
    "Country": null,
    "Mobile": null,
    "Home": null,
    "Email": null,
    "LeadSource": 0
}
```

I'm assuming that I should be mapping the response back differently but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but with all this explicit mapping, wouldn't it just be easier to create your own manual maps?

Comment: This code is source generated from the domain model so it really doesn't make too much difference

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the mapper to the following seems to have solved it:

```cs
CreateMap<Customer, GetAllPagedCustomersResponse>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Number, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Address.Number))
    .ForMember(m => m.Postcode, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Address.Postcode))
    .ForMember(m => m.Street, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Address.Street))
    .ForMember(m => m.Locality, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Address.Locality))
    .ForMember(m => m.Town, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Address.Town))
    .ForMember(m => m.County, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Address.County))
    .ForMember(m => m.Country, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Address.Country))
    .ForMember(m => m.Mobile, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Contact.Mobile))
    .ForMember(m => m.Home, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Contact.Home))
    .ForMember(m => m.Email, options => options.MapFrom(p => p.Contact.Email))
    .ReverseMap();
```

I would have thought I could still use the version that worked on the DTO's mapping to the entity with `.ReverseMap()` but apparently I have to switch the order and map the properties like this :/

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers